# Call the previous class WinDev 21

Tags: android, windev

Anyone know if it's possible make a call from one class to the class that has created it?

Class1 has an instance of Class2, I want to call a method of Class1 from Class2.

Among them there is none inheritance relationship.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the way myself.

I made in Class1 this methods:

```
PROCEDURE Create()

 oClass.NewClass(object)

PROCEDURE TestMethod()

 Info("ok")
```

And in Class2 this:

```
PROCEDURE NewClass(oClass1 is dynamic object)

 oClass1.TestMethod()
```

So when I call Class1.Create() It shows "ok"